# Access OS X Mail message by its ID

Tags: applescript

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to get a Mail message (located in the 'Drafts' folder) by its message id.

The following code:

```
set theContent to getContent(123456)

on getContent(theID)

  tell application "Mail"       
    try
      return ((content of message whose message id is theID) as rich text)
    on error errText number errNum
      display dialog "Error: " & errNum & return & errText
    end try

  end tell

end getContent
```

Generates an error that reads: `Error -1723.  Can't get the content of message whose message id = 123456.  Access not allowed.`

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not AppleScript, but if you just want to see the message, you can pull it up by opening the URL `message://<YOUR-MESSAGE-ID@HERE>`. Via http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mac-message.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Mail" to get content of (first message of drafts mailbox whose id = 123456)
```